# tengo una lista con varios elementos y una lista de diccionarios

Tags: python-3.x

tengo una lista:

```
mascotas[ perro, gato, gorrion, pez ]
```

y una lista de diccionarios con nombres:

```
nombres[ 
    { Nombre:Carlos },
    { Nombre:Miguel },
    { Nombre:Laura },
    { Nombre:Carmen } 
]
```

debo asignar mascotas a los nombres de manera aleatoria, sin repetir y que se me añada en cada diccionario con la clave Mascota:

```
import random 
index = random.randint( 0, 4 ) 
nombres.append( mascotas[ index ] )
for x in usuario:
```

aquí es donde empieza el error porque nada mas me agrega 1 sola mascota aleatoria.

pero

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import random
import sys

NOMBRE_DICT_KEY = "Nombre"
MASCOTA_DICT_KEY = "Mascota"

mascotas = [ "perro", "gato", "gorrion", "pez" ]
nombres = [
    { NOMBRE_DICT_KEY: "Carlos" },
    { NOMBRE_DICT_KEY: "Miguel" },
    { NOMBRE_DICT_KEY: "Laura" },
    { NOMBRE_DICT_KEY: "Carmen" } 
]

nombres_length = len(nombres)
if nombres_length == 0:
    sys.exit()

random.shuffle(mascotas)
nombres_index = 0
for mascota in mascotas:
    if nombres_index >= nombres_length:
        break
    
    nombres[nombres_index][MASCOTA_DICT_KEY] = mascota
    nombres_index += 1

print(nombres)
```

Comment: Hola Jacobo, las respuestas que son solo código, son consideradas de baja calidad, te sugiero que edites la tuya, y expliques de que forma resuelve el problema planteado, así evitarás que sea cerrada y/o recibir votos negativos. ver [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
import random

mascotas = [ "perro", "gato", "gorrion", "pez" ] 

nombres = [  
    { "Nombre":"Carlos" },
    { "Nombre":"Migue" },
    { "Nombre":"Laura" },
    { "Nombre":"Carmen" } 
]



for i in range( len( mascotas )):

       # generamos un aleatorio
    index = random.randint( 0, len( mascotas ) -1 ) 

       # agregamos al diccionario, un nuevo par "key, value"
    nombres[ i ].update({ "Mascota": mascotas[ index ] })
  
       # quitamos de la lista, el indice usado
    mascotas.pop( index )

print( nombres )
```

Comment: muchas gracias. solo me hace 2 iteraciones y ya a la 3era me da error

Comment: y el aleatorio me repite animales

Comment: Gracias por el comentario, ya lo corregí.